# How do I remove some rows with NA values for selected columns, after assigning it a variable?

Tags: r, variables, na, delete-row

I have a dateframe with NA values in one of the columns, I have assigned it to variable with the below code:

```
missing_weight <- subset(baseball, is.na(weight))
```

this gave me a set of rows with NA value under weight column.

I am looking to now remove missing_weight from the original dataframe 'baseball' and update the baseball dataframe with no NA value for weight.

Comment: `missing_weight <- subset(baseball, !is.na(weight))` ?

Comment: Thanks! I was looking to see if I can assign the NA rows to a variable first and then remove those rows from the main data frame. Something along these lines? basesball <- baseball[complete.cases(!missing_weight),] ??? This gives an error message but I am looking to somehow use the variable to remove those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `dplyr::anti_join` will help.

```
missing_weight <- subset(baseball, is.na(weight))
weight <- dplyr::anti_join(baseball, missing_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
baseball %>% 
    filter(is.na(weight)) %>%
     anti_join(baseball, .)
```